# why roles are not active directly after registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In registration form  I add different roles `[ "Candidate","Junior","Senior"]`
it's work but roles not active directly after registration but if I logout & login again it working

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { 
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email               
        };

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.rol);

            return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");                 
        }

        AddErrors(result);
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is `model.rol`?

Comment: is attribute (string) to get roles nam as [ "Candidate"or"Junior"or"Senior"] in dropdownlist in the view

Comment: I assume you mean "property"? Assuming you are using the default project template, you most likely need to move `UserManager.AddToRole` before `SignInManager.SignInAsync`.

Comment: yes I am using default project template

Comment: yes thank it workig

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your roles are added as claims to the user's principal, which is set only upon login.